# How do I create a preface page *before* the title page in Quarto

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, quarto

I am using quarto, python, and jupyter lab/notebook to be able to create reproducible reports. Our reports include a preface page before the title page with additional information about what is included in the report. So, how do I place content before the title page? The final document will be a .pdf.

After much googling I suspect it has something to do with modifying before-body.tex but it wasn't clear to me if or how I could move the title page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use [`before-body.tex`](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/blob/main/src/resources/formats/pdf/pandoc/before-body.tex) latex template partials. Include your preface contents before the title.

**before-body.tex**

```latex
$if(has-frontmatter)$
\frontmatter
$endif$

% -----------  PREFACE ----------

\begin{center}
\Large{Preface}
\end{center}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vulputate bibendum
mauris vel aliquam. Fusce vulputate non ligula vitae accumsan
% -------------------------------

$if(title)$
$if(beamer)$
\frame{\titlepage}
$else$
\maketitle
$endif$
$if(abstract)$
\begin{abstract}
$abstract$
\end{abstract}
$endif$
$endif$
```

And, then use this template partial in the YAML of the `ipynb` file.

[image: snapshot of the ipynb file in the jupyterlab]